# Remove last character from JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I'm writing a vt100 emulator and I'm using a JTextPane with a DefaultStyledDocument to display the formatted text. Now I want to implement the backspace, so i need to be able to remove the last character.

I tried the following:

```
doc.remove(doc.getEndPosition().getOffset()-1, doc.getEndPosition().getOffset());
```

But I keep getting a 'javax.swing.text.BadLocationException: Invalid remove'

How should this be done?

Comment: To fully elucidate and demonstrate your problem, consider creating and posting a small compilable and runnable program that demonstrates the problem for us, an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the API wrong.  The last parameter is the number of characters to remove which in your case should be 1.

Here is the API for [`Document.remove(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#remove%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I misuntherstood the javadoc. I'm still puzzeling on how to get it to work. With this statement: doc.remove(doc.getLength()-2, 1); i can only remove a character once.

Comment: That statement removes one character. Are you saying it doesn't work if you call it again?

Comment: I have found the right characterpositions. The last character can be removed by doc.remove(doc.getLength()-2, 2);.